# Editing a modal (dialog) submission

Tags: knockout.js

### [Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/94Ltx/2/)

*Partially working, I can render the dialog, add N submissions and delete one - but I can't edit... yet*

---

I've created a custom binding handler that renders a jQuery UI dialog showing a list of sub-questions. Once these have been completed and the *Save Changes* button is pressed it takes a copy of the observable using `ko.toJS(observable)` and adds that to an array, which subsequently gets added to the `observableArray` on my view model, like this.

```
var submission = [];
viewModel.selectedQuestion().subQuestions().forEach(function (sq) {
    submission.push(ko.toJS(sq));
});
viewModel.submissions.push(submission);
```

I've attached a function to the view model that deletes a given submission like this.

```
viewModel.deleteSubmission = function (submission) {
    var index = 0;
    viewModel.submissions().forEach(function (s) {
        if (s === submission) {
            viewModel.submissions.splice(index, 1);
        }
        index++;
    });
};
```

But I'm a little stumped on how I can edit a submission, rendering the dialog again with a given model.  I'm aware of `ko.renderTemplate` and am currently experimenting with this route, but I think the `ko.toJS` copy I'm adding to my submissions array is preventing Knockout doing its thing.

Does anyone have any pointers to push me in the right direction?  I'm currently reading through [a simple editor pattern in Knockout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html) so I'm pretty confident I can handle all the `commit` and `rollback` when cancelling out of the edit dialog - I'm just not sure how I can edit saved submissions.

---

#### Attempt 1: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcaldredbann/94Ltx/3/)

I've created a second custom binding handler called `editSubmissionDialog` and added a `selectedSubmission` to my view model. This is opening the dialog - but because of the `ko.toJS` (I think) the items passed to the dialog aren't observable. Also, do I really have to create another custom binding handler that uses the same dialog, hopefully not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Ltx/4/)

---

Managed to do this in a way that I liked, essentially I'm `.splice`ing the collection of submissions at a given index.

**The bindings**

```
<div class="submissions" data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.submissions, as: 'submission' }">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: $data, as: 'question' }">
            <tr>
                <td class="key" data-bind="text: question.text"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: question.answer"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.deleteSubmission">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The function**

```
self.deleteSubmission = function (submission) {
    var index = self.submissions().indexOf(submission);
    self.submissions.splice(index, 1);
};
```

More details in the [provided working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94Ltx/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You binding handler is very strange, you have dependencies to the VM from the handler.
Check out my dialog example here which uses a more generic approach with templates.

http://jsfiddle.net/H8xWY/107/

Its using a member on the dialogItem to tell which template to load

```
this.dialogItem({ template: "dialog-template-one", message: "Dialog one data", title: "Databindable title" });
```

it uses the dialog binding from this collection of bindings i wrote
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings

Comment: Certainly an interesting way you're doing stuff there - but it's a little out-of-scope for what I'm trying to achieve with the brunt of the work being done in the custom binding. Perhaps something I'll look at a little later, but a bit to complex for now.